Use a calculated list in list_transform
I wonder how to use data in list_transform
Let's say I have this :
SELECT filename, 
min(tpep_pickup_datetime), 
max(tpep_pickup_datetime), 
avg(total_amount)
FROM read_parquet(
    list_transform(
        generate_series(1, 6),
        n -> format('https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/yellow_tripdata_2023-{:02d}.parquet', n) 
    ), filename=true
)
GROUP BY filename
ORDER BY filename;

Let's say that instead of generate_series(1, 6), I get a list calculated in a SQL request, can I use this list in list_transform.
This example does not work. How to make it work ?
with a as (select [1,6] as a_list) -- << Normally, [1,6] would come from data
SELECT filename, 
min(tpep_pickup_datetime), 
max(tpep_pickup_datetime), 
avg(total_amount)
FROM read_parquet(
    list_transform(
        a.a_list, -- << Change HERE (doesn't work)
        n -> format('https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/yellow_tripdata_2023-{}.parquet', n) 
    ), filename=true
)
GROUP BY filename
ORDER BY filename;


Let's start with something that's both relevant and simple:
SELECT list_transform( [1,6], n -> format('{}.parquet', n) ) col;

This produces:
┌────────────────────────┐
│          col           │
│       varchar[]        │
├────────────────────────┤
│ [1.parquet, 6.parquet] │
└────────────────────────┘

Now let's suppose that the problem you're confronting boils down to
being
able to replace [1,6] above with
something computed using a CTE along the lines you indicated:
with a as (select [1,6] as a_list) ...

The way to combine these two elements is as follows:
with a as (select [1,6] as a_list)
SELECT list_transform(
  (select a_list from a),
  n -> format('{}.parquet', n) 
);

